# Can I use dictation in MacOS with Apple Watch?

Tags: macos, apple-watch, voice-dictation

Dictation is great in MacOS, Apple watch is also a great gadget always follows us. Can I use Apple watch as voice input source to Dictation?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say no. You can not set the Apple Watch as an audio input source.

Answer (score 1):

macOS Monterey does not support Apple Watch as a sound input device. You’ll want to use AirPods or another supported microphone.